# I need to process a DocumentSnapShot single document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter and am writing a new app. In the app I want to retrieve the user data from a firebase document and populate TextFields on the user screen. I can pull the data fine using DocumentSnapShot. I want to use TextEditingController and populate it with the data but I am not able to do it. I know the data is there since I can see it in debug mode. Below are snippets of my code.
Here is where I get the data and populate the TextEditingControllers:

```
final agentsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('agents'));

getCurrentAgent() async {
  final DocumentSnapshot currentAgent =
      await agentsRef.doc(globals.currentUid).get();

 if (currentAgent == null) {
      emailController.text = "";
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final agentProvider =
        Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context, listen: false);
        agentProvider.loadValues(Agents());
      });
    } else {
      // existing record
      // Updates Controllers
      **emailController.text = currentAgent.data[index].toString(); // THIS LINE IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE**
      // Updates State
      new Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
        final agentProvider =
        Provider.of<AgentProvider>(context, listen: false);
        agentProvider.loadValues(widget.agents);
      });
    }
 @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentAgent();
    super.initState();
  }
```

How do I access each data element in the DocumentSnapShot?

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically get the fields by their **name** and not by their index. So:

```
**emailController.text = currentAgent.data()["email"].toString();
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tried that as well and I get the message that the operator "[]" is not defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> function(). How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure? That's how I get data from a document in my own code, and also how its shown here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read

Comment: I found the answer to my issue. I need to change this:emailController.text = currentAgent.data["email"].toString();  to this emailController.text = currentAgent.data()["email"].toString(); It works great now.

Comment: Oh wow... good catch. I overlooked this multiple times. 